# Soapui or Rest Service Testing? and where I can find good Soapui and rest service testing tutorials?

Tags: automated-testing, soapui, web-service, api-testing

I want learn Soapui or Rest Service Testing, so could you please let me know which one is good for me? as per your knowledge/Experience.

Before today I discussed the same with my colleagues, some people said Soap and some Rest. So to avoid this confusion I am posting my query here.

*As per me both are good, but I want to learn only one.*

I want to learn basics and I do not have change to apply it.

*Expected:* Please suggest me which one I need to learn for my future and also tutorials for the same.

*Note:* Right now I have knowledge on Soapui (Only - Creating project, Creating test case, Creating test suite, Creating  assert (Only-contains)).

*Your suggestions are valuable for me.*

Comment: Doesn't it really depend on what path YOU want to go on and where you see your career going?  My advice may not be the career path you want to choose.

Comment: @MichaelF: I like to learn new things and want to learn API testing. I am the least knowledge/experience person in our team. But this is a challenge for me to learn new things, so decided to learn API testing (For now). _I really appreciate your response_.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As for tutorials on SoapUI, sadly the majority of them are sub-par at best and out of date. If you want to learn SoapUI the best option is likely to jump in feet first and hit the ground running.

My background is primarily API testing, with a specialty with SoapUI and Groovy, so I will try and give some hints and pointers to get you started.

***SoapUI's core only transmits data***

In it's core, all SoapUI does is open up a socket and sends and receives a request. This is an extremely simple concept that once you understand, it will make your life a lot easier. The ability to change this request on the fly is where SoapUI becomes difficult. This is where the scripting language, groovy, comes into play.

***Groovy is Java's little brother***

Learning Java will drastically improve your skillset with SoapUI's groovy scripting language. The majority of the skill with SoapUI is in the Groovy scripting, so if you want to become an expert in API testing and SoapUI, learn Java and Groovy.

***Learn APIs inside and out***

Learn all about APIs. A decent place to start is the [SoapUI API Dojo](http://www.soapui.org/Dojo/overview.html). It covers a brief overview of APIs and the future of them. The second step I would take would be developing a very basic API using Java or C# in order to learn how APIs work and the type of code that is being developed for them. Also, if you use Java, this will strengthen your Groovy skills.

***Leverage the SoapUI API***

Leveraging the [SoapUI API](http://www.soapui.org/apidocs/overview-summary.html) for information and learning how to google it will become extremely beneficial. They use a rather odd but easy to understand naming convention that will make it a little bit easier to navigate.

***Learn by using SoapUI Source***

As an open source project, you can import SoapUI into Java projects and dig through the source code. By importing into a Java project this will give you a better intellisense style functionality and allow for you to understand the objects within the scripting language a lot easier. Afterwards, you can easily convert the majority of Java projects into Groovy script and use them in SoapUI's groovy directly, build add ons or even run it directly from a Java project.

***Become an active member on the SoapUI forums***

And last but definitely not least, be active on the [SoapUI forums](http://forum.soapui.org/). Both asking and answering questions. My name there is PaulM, feel free to contact me if you ever need anything, but first ask questions and become familiar with the site. This will lead to a lot more experience than most anything else can give you in API testing since you will be helping and reading a variety of different problems and solutions that other people have ran into with SoapUI.

***And some references that will help you get started***

[SoapUI's Rest Guide](http://www.soapui.org/REST-Testing/getting-started.html)

[LearnSoapUI Blog](http://learnsoapui.wordpress.com/) <-- Very useful for scripting help

[Ole Lensmar's (CTO of Smartbear) Blog](http://olensmar.blogspot.com/) <---- Very useful for Plugin development

[Example Groovy Scripts](http://webservice-testing.blogspot.com/p/groovy-scripts.html)

Comment: very nice.. Wow..

Comment: As per you created account @ SoapUI forums but unable to login (Showing - The specified username is currently inactive....).

Comment: Really nice @Paul..

Comment: @QA4it It has been a long time since I signed up but it might require email activation. I do know that during the login all of the username has to be in lowercase (or possibly original case). I should probably report a but with them regarding that.

Answer (score 1):

PackT Publishing also sell a SoapUi book that is quite in-depth.

Mark.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link http://www.testingbrain.com/tutorials/soapui-tutorial.html . There you can find some pdf tutorials about SoapUI

Comment: Your answer needs context to be relevant: please edit your answer and add a summary of the information presented at the site you linked. That way the key information is available here should the link to the site or the site itself ever be taken down.

Comment: I'm torn. Part of me says this is actually exactly what the question asks for. Where can OP find soapui tutorials? And it makes me think it's not the answer that's bad, but rather the question. So the information that I would edit into the answer is "What makes this tutorial better or different than other tutorials?" and stuff like that.