# How to create automation framework for automation of REST APIs?

Tags: automated-testing, test-automation-framework, rest-api, api

Currently, I am using JMeter to automate APIs but I have been asked to form a framework that is quicker and convenient to use for everyone in the team and a framework that preferably involves reading Rest API requests/headers/payload/URL from an excel sheet so that everyone in the QA team just adds to it and get's rolling with minimal efforts.

I have no idea how to proceed with the aforementioned requests of creating REST API automation framework. Please suggest with step by step detailed instructions, Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Soapui or Rest Service Testing? and where I can find good Soapui and rest service testing tutorials?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/9874/soapui-or-rest-service-testing-and-where-i-can-find-good-soapui-and-rest-servic)

Comment: The answers to the aforementioned are mainly about SOAP UI (I'm more concerned about REST APIs). Also, the answers don't talk about framework level ideas, Thanks!

Comment: You can implement one with any language (Java, NodeJs, C#, python, ruby, VBA...) as long as it provides a way to send requests. Though your post is not specific enough to provide an adequate answer.

Answer (score 4):

**REST-Assured is one good option.**

I have used it with Java. It's a really good option and gives you the flexibility to do a lot when it comes to API testing.

Refer to the below link for further details related to using Rest-Assured.

[using REST-Assured](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage)

Comment: Many thanks for writing in! Yes, I also read about REST-Assured and I have got started with it and automated few APIs as well thus far. Just need a few suggestions:

- How do I do things at a framework level?
- How do I handle the reporting part?
- I have written all the payload in the code itself. Is that a good practice? If not then how do I read payload from any other resource like sheet etc?
- Any other practices for ensuing a good REST-Assured testing framework?

Comment: Hello Rohan, sorry am not getting time to work on your questions. But will reply by end of the day tomorrow. I have seen your questions. Cheers!

Comment: @RohanKalia here's a comparison between REST-assured and Karate: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ETTrdMVcBXaPjdKY-_67zCWBsi2Ctc5DIQUIfr02H7A/edit - this answers all these questions (disclaimer: am dev of Karate)

Comment: Hello Rohan, Here are the answers to your questions. So, framework depends on the nature of APIs. It entirely depends on you on how you want to organize your testware. It largely depends what makes things easier for you.  For reporting, you can use TestNG reports or extent reports. I am more inclined towards extent reports because of better presentation. Writing payloads in the code is not a good practice. You should keep your payloads at some common location and have some common program to read the payload data from the file. Keep the payload in excel file and read the payloads

Comment: You can write a function in java to read from excel. This function can be a part of your framework.

Comment: See framework is more or less a skeleton or the way you organize your code. So, that it is easier to make changes, do updates and create scripts effectively ensuring the reusability of code. The question about framework seems like generic. Sorry, could not understand exactly what inputs do you need from the framework standpoint

Comment: @Aalok Please suggest what's better keeping the payload in JSON file or an excel sheet. Also can you please send me a sample code how to read it from an excel sheet or even a file for that matter!

Comment: I would suggest you to keep the payloads in JSON file only and then you can parse the JSONs. And I am sorry, I don’t have the code with me since we did that in one of the projects in my last company. I will try to get you some sample code to parse the JSONs.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/).  It allows for header manipulation and reading from data sources like excel.  It can also send multiple types of payloads including JSON, XML and text.  There is a shared team workspace which you can use to share collections amongst the team.

It's good up until you need to do data validation against a database.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [**Karate**](https://github.com/intuit/karate), a REST testing framework on top of Cucumber.

Answer (score 0):

You should try out postman for REST API Automation. It is having lots of ability. You can Import JSON files you can try out Collection runner for Automation you can you Test Scripts of Postman tool from right-hand side of postman for more details "https://blog.imaginea.com/api-automation-using-postman/" check this blog it will be helpful